# Lazy random walk hitting time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, markov-chains, random-walk

Suppose we have a lazy random walk $(S_0, S_1, S_2,...)$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ starting from $S_0 =0$ biased to the right, i.e. $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n X_k$ with $\mathbb{P}(X_1=1)=p$,  $\mathbb{P}(X_1=0)=q$,  $\mathbb{P}(X_1=-1)=r$ and $p>r$ and $p+q+r=1$. The $X_i$'s are also assumed to be i.i.d. with only exception $X_0=0$.

Can we evaluate the quantity $\mathbb{P}(T_{-1}>n)$ where $T_{-1} = \inf \{ k \geq 0: S_k=-1 \}$ is the first hitting time of $-1$ ? My guess is that $\mathbb{P}(T_{-1}=\infty)>0$, so I want to prove this fact (and obtain an expression for $\mathbb{P}(T_{-1}=\infty)$ depending on $p$ and $q$) by showing that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}(T_{-1}>n) > 0$.

Comment: If $h_n=P_n(T_{-1}<\infty)$, then $h_n$ satisfies, $h_{-1}=1$ and $h_n=ph_{n+1}+qh_n+rh_{n-1}$. If you can solve this recurrence relation, you can obtain $h_0$ and then $P_0(T_{-1}=\infty)=1-h_0$.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Since the walk is biased to the right, isn't it the case that $h_n=1$ for $n\leq -2$ ? Then, it seems that $h_n=1$ for all $n$ is the only possible solution... something's wrong.

Comment: I don't understand why the expression $T_{-1}=\inf\{k\geq 0 \ :\  S_k=-1\}$ can mean the first time hitting $-1$. Shouldn't $S_k$ be $X_k$, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Shashi The $X_k$'s are the increments, the actual walk is described by the trajectory $(S_0, S_1,S_2,...)$. So, $\{k\geq 0: S_k = -1\}$ is the set of all time instants where the walk is at $-1$, and the infimum (minimum) of that set is just the first time instant.

Comment: @Nocturne nvm now I understand.

Comment: @Nocturne i don’t think that is the case. See Shashi’s answer which fleshes out the hint I gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\PM}{\mathbb{P}}$Your main interest is the expression for $\PM(T_{-1}=\infty)$? Then it is much easier to just go for that instead of calculating $\PM(T_{-1}>n)$ first. The reason for that is because $\PM(T_{-1}=\infty)$ is the probability of never hitting $-1$ starting at $0$ and it is easy to calculate the probability of ever hitting $-1$ starting at $0$. Define the following:
\begin{align}
f_n:=\PM(\text{ever hitting} -1 \text{ starting at } n)
\end{align}
Clearly $f_{-1}=1$ moreover one has $$\tag{1}f_0 = r + qf_0+ pf_1$$
Now I give you an exercise, namely to prove that $f_1 = f_0 f_0$.  So $(1)$ becomes:
$$f_0 = r + qf_0+ pf_0^2$$ This has two solutions, namely:
\begin{align}
f_0 = \frac{r}{p} \ \ \vee \ \ f_0 = 1
\end{align}
Take $r=0$ and immediately see that $f_0=1$ fells off, hence $f_0 = \frac{r}{p}$. Finally:
\begin{align}
\PM(T_{-1}=\infty) = 1- f_0 = 1-\frac{r}{p}
\end{align}

Comment: Can you please give me a hint as to why $f_1 = f_0 f_0$?

Comment: @Batrachotoxin Strong Markov property (also note that on the event arriving at -1 started from 1 we have to arrive at 0 a.s.)

Comment: Got it!! Thank you so much :)